# Returning a promise object instead during retrieval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, ipfs

I have a mapping and in each mapping i want to get data in the file storage IPFS such as the name. Then I want to return the name on the interface. However, I get a "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." Can someone please help me? been trying to solve this for hours. Can't seem to understand why because I know that hName should be a string.

```
{this.props.hawkers.map((hawker, key) => {
          const hawkerDetails = axios
            .get("https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/" + hawker.profileHash)
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log("this is the data: ", response.data);
              return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });

          const hName = hawkerDetails.then((details) => {
            return hName;
          });
 return (
            <>
              <h4 style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: 20 }}>
                <Link
                  to={`/hawkerInfo/${hawker.owner}`}
                  // state={{ chosenHawkerPk: hawker.owner }}
                  state={{ chosenHawkerPk: hawker }}
                >
                  {hName}
                </Link>
              </h4>
```

Comment: what do you see if you console.log inside this function? 

const hName = hawkerDetails.then((details) => {
            console.log(details)
          });

I am wondering if the name could be on details.hName or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on.

1. You're not using [React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage your data.
2. You're passing in `details`as  an argument to your `then` method, and then not using it so `hName` is meaningless. It should probably be `details.hName`.
3. Ideally you want to create an array [of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and *then* process the data with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). In my example I've used [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).
4. Once you've set your state you *then* need to `map` over your data in your `return` to create the HTML.

```js
// Initialise state
const [ hawkers, setHawkers ] = useState([]);

// Async function called by the `useEffect` method
async function getData() {

  // Create a list of Axios promises
  const promises = this.props.hawkers.map(hawker => {
    const url = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${hawker.profileHash}`;
    return axios.get(url);
  });

  // Wait for all the data to return
  const responses = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Use `map` to return a new array of each response's data
  const hawkers = data.map(response => response.data);

  // Set the state with that array
  setNames(hawkers);
}

// useEffect runs once if you pass in an empty
// array dependency
useEffect(() {
  getData();
}, []);

if (!hawkers.length) return <div>Loading</div>;

// Now just `map` over the data that you put in state
return (
  <>
    {hawkers.map(hawker => {
      <h4>
        <Link to={`/hawkerInfo/${hawker.details.owner}`}>
          {hawker.details.name}
        </Link>
      </h4>
    })};
  </>
)
```

Comment: Hii thank u for ur answer. But this only works for functionality component right? Because I am using a class component. Do u know how I can do it on a class component instead?

Comment: Instead of `useEffect` use `componentDidMount`, and set state as `this.state = { hawkers: [] };` in the constructor,  and then use `this.setState({ hawkers })` at the end of the function. You can then iterate over `this.state.hawkers` in the render.